# Unable to show data into report viewer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, reporting, reportviewer

I've one to many relationship such as tblStudent and tblInstallments. I'm trying to get data from tblInstallments on the base of matching roll numbers and showing in report table using reportviewer. But I'm getting following exception while running report.

> *ERROR:- Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.*

I'm here for kind help from the techies.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the problem with reportviewer, Problem is with your query that is returning dataset for your report .Please check your Query/Stored Procedure.

- duplicate rows are returning from your query which has same primary key.
- Or query is resulting null column while in database table design it is not set to AllowDBNull .